# « — Je vais me battre à jeun ! — A jeung ! Il vient d'avoir l'accent ! » : quel accent et comment prononce-t-on ici ?

Tags: histoire, accents-régionaux

Dans le classique de Rostand, [*Cyrano de Bergerac*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac_%28Rostand%29)([texte](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1256/1256-h/1256-h.htm)), il y a une référence à un *accent* particulier à l'*acte IV, scène 4.VII*. On se trouve au [siège d'Arras](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si%C3%A8ge_d%27Arras_%281640%29) et *de Guiche* a quitté la scène. Entre temps Ragueneau a distribué des vivres à la compagnie des Cadets, affamés, de sorte qu'ils festoient. C'est à ce moment que De Guiche revient, et il est surpris de la mine de certains soldats. Puis Roxanne annonce qu'elle décide de rester, et de Guiche la seconde:

> PREMIER CADET: Seriez-vous un Gascon malgré votre guipure ?
>
> ROXANE: Quoi !. . .
>
> DE GUICHE: Je ne quitte pas une femme en danger.
>
> DEUXIÈME CADET (*au premier*): Dis donc ! Je crois qu'on peut lui donner
>   à manger ! (*Toutes les victuailles reparaissent comme par
>   enchantement*.)
>
> DE GUICHE (*dont les yeux s'allument*): Des vivres !
>
> UN TROISIÈME CADET: Il en sort de sous toutes les vestes !
>
> DE GUICHE (*se maîtrisant, avec hauteur*): Est-ce que vous croyez que je
>   mange vos restes ?
>
> CYRANO (*saluant*): Vous faites des progrès !
>
> DE GUICHE (*fièrement, et à qui échappe sur le dernier mot une légère
>   pointe d'accent*): Je vais me battre à jeun !
>
> PREMIER CADET (*exultant de joie*): A **jeung** ! Il vient d'avoir l'accent
>   !
>
> DE GUICHE (*riant*): Moi ?
>
> LE CADET: C'en est un ! (*Ils se mettent tous à danser*.)

De quel accent s'agit-il précisément et en quoi ça diffère de [(a)ʒ œ ̃] i.e. comment s'inscrit la *légère pointe d'accent* dans le *jeun**g*** de Rostand? <sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Il serait aussi intéressant de savoir si c'est [*Gascon*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gascon) à proprement parler, ou [*Occitan*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan), et à quelle particularité de l'une ou de l'autre réfère-t-on ici par le truchement du mot (*à) [jeun](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jeun)*? Finalement, je me demande accessoirement à quelle région c'est associé... quand Christian arrive chez les cadet, alors que Cyrano va raconter son combat à la porte de Nesle, il demande a Carbon: "Que fait-on quand on trouve Des Méridionaux trop vantards ?. . ." et Carbon de lui répondre: "On leur prouve Qu'on peut être du Nord, et courageux."(acte II, scène 2.VII). Sont-ils tous "du Nord" avec un accent du Sud-Ouest?? Y a-t-il un lien entre cet échange et ce dont il est question ici, à savoir l'accent?</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le `g` final dénote le son [ŋ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_nasale_v%C3%A9laire_vois%C3%A9e) (une consonne occlusive nasale vélaire voisée pour les intimes), qui ressemble à [ng]. En français « standard », on trouve ce son dans les mots en `-ing` (*parking*, *smoking*, …) chez certains locuteurs — on entend aussi [ng] ou [ŋg].

Le [ŋ] en finale dans un mot qui se termine par une voyelle nasale est une caracactéristique de l'[accent du Midi](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francitan), qui correspond en gros à la région où l'on parlait autrefois [occitan](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan). C'est en fait plus précisément une caractéristique du sud-ouest, connu en France comme l'accent [toulousain](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toulouse) (c'est la plus grande ville de la région caractérisée). Cette zone est plus étendue que la [Gascogne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gascogne) (qui est en gros la partie de la France au sud-ouest de Toulouse, Toulouse exclue).

Donc *jeun* se prononce [ʒœ̃] dans le nord de la France, et y est d'ailleurs prononcé de comme [ʒɛ̃] (dans le nord, on ne distingue pas ou peu *jeun* et *brun* *geint* et *brin*). Dans le sud, les sons [œ̃] et [ɛ̃] sont bien distincts, et on entend une sorte de `g` à la fin : [ʒœ̃ŋ].

Voir plus généralement :

- [Accents de France](http://french.about.com/library/listening/bllg-accents-translation.htm)
- [Le dialecte français de Toulouse](http://occitanet.free.fr/tolosan/tolosan.htm)
- [La tête au carré : les accents régionaux](http://www.franceinter.fr/emission-la-tete-au-carre-les-accents-regionaux) (je n'ai pas écouté mais c'est sûrement intéressant)
- [putaing-cong](http://desencyclopedie.wikia.com/wiki/Putaing-cong) — la page est souvent à prendre au second degré, mais *putaing-cong* est effectivement une expression typique de la région toulousaine, où elle veut dire à peu près « zut » voire « oh », alors que *putain* et *con* sont des mots très grossiers dans le nord.

Comment: Merci pour une réponse complète et les ressources! Je pensais que c'était plus près du mot _daim_ - comme _geint_ finalement mais sans la sorte de _g_. Je peux concevoir avec ou sans g, je trouve ce dernier plus "aigu", à défaut de savoir exactement comment le décrire. Je n'aurais jamais compris que c'était toulousain. Merci encore!

Comment: @Amphiteóth *daim* et *geint* ont la même voyelle : [dɛ̃], [ʒɛ̃].

Comment: Je me souviens tres bien de tourangeaux (de souche) qui avaient cet accent : *Il y a un laping dans le jarding*, ou le *ing* sonnait comme *sang* et *rang* en anglais.

Comment: @Drew Ah bon, des Tourangeaux ? Pourtant, ce n'est pas dans le midi, Tours. C'est même censé être un français « sans accent ». [Exemple (avec un enregistrement)](http://rue89.nouvelobs.com/2011/07/04/laccent-de-tours-le-plus-pur-de-france-bah-plus-tant-quca-212153). Tu es sûr qu'ils n'étaient pas d'une campagne plus au sud ?

Comment: Oui, je sais bien ce que c'est cense etre. ;-) C'est pourquoi je l'ai dit. C'etait, en particulier, dans les annees 1980s, de la bouche d'un homme, travailleur (~paysan), qui avait ~55 ans, et qui a vecu toute sa vie a Montlouis (tout pres de Tours) - et ses ancetres aussi. Et il n'etait pas le seul. C'etait presque un patois (a mon oreille) - parfois difficile a comprendre. Le tourangeau bourgeois et le tourangeau paysan n'ont peut-etre pas le meme accent. ;-)

Comment: Oui certes, mais j'entends au final des nuances comme _ajun/ajain/ajingue/ajingne/ajaigne_. Merci!

Comment: "C'est en fait plus précisément une caractéristique du sud-ouest" -> Pas seulement, ce [ŋ] final est aussi présent en Provence.

Comment: N'hésitez pas à produire des réponses supplémentaires; ce serait fort intéressant de vous lire avec plus amples explications!

Answer (score 1):

Cette finale palatisée effectivement s'entend dans tout le Midi, y compris le sud-est comme à Marseille par exemple. Mon fils écoutait volontiers un disque des *Lettres de mon moulin* quand il était tout petit, et il nous demanda ce que voulait dire : « Revieng, revieng, criait la trompe » dans « La chèvre de monsieur Seguin », ne connaissant pas cet accent provençal en Île-de-France …