# Oignon/ognon : découpage syllabique ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, linguistique

Pour *l'espèce de plante herbacée bisannuelle de la famille des Amaryllidaceae* cultivée depuis l'antiquité et possiblement originaire d’Asie centrale ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oignon#Histoire)), on a l'[*oignon*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oignon)/ognon [ɔ ɳ ɔ ̃] ([rectifié en 1990](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990), présenté [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17668)), du latin *unionem*, 12<sup>e</sup> [*unniun*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/oignon), 13<sup>e</sup> *hunion*, *oingnun*, *ognon*, 14<sup>e</sup> *oignon* (DHLF/Rey). Et on l'avait donc déjà eu émincé de la sorte (ognon), et apparaissant dans [*Ac.5*](http://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/ognon) (1798) jusqu'à [*Ac.8*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/oignon) (1935) (aussi au [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/oignon)). Le *TLFi* réfère à un article abordant la prononciation orthographique ([*poigne*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poigne), [pwaɳ], [pɔ ɳ]) par opposition à la suppression de *i* ([*rogne*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rogne), [ʀ ɔ ɳ]).

---

1. Quel est le [découpage syllabique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabe#D.C3.A9coupage_syllabique), à l'écrit et à
   l'oral, du mot *o(i)gnon* ?
2. Le *g* dans ce mot est-il une [consonne ambisyllabique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabe#Cas_des_consonnes_ambisyllabiques) ?

   - Le cas échéant, comme « *on considère que la consonne, en plus
     de former l'attaque de la seconde syllabe, est également comprise
     dans la [coda](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_syllabique) de la première* », pourquoi on n'entend pas [ɔ[g](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3709)] en début de mot ?
   - Est-ce le rôle de cette consonne qui explique qu'on n'ait pas [[gn](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3649)ɔ] en finale d'ognon, alors qu'on a [*gnose*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/gnose) [gno:z] ou [*gnou*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/gnou) [gnu] (aussi [ɳu]) ; qui explique qu'on n'ait pas non plus [ɔnniɔ] ?
3. Peut-on savoir que le premier *o* [ɔ] de ognon est prononcé différemment du mot *eau* [o] en se fiant à l'orthographe du mot ? Peut-on prononcer [o] et si oui, cela affecte-t-il le découpage syllabique ?

Comment: " Historiquement, la lettre « i » servait à « mouiller » la graphie gn afin qu’« oignon » ne se prononce pas comme « gnou »." Source: projet voltaire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Quel est le découpage syllabique, à l'écrit et à l'oral, du mot o(i)gnon ?

Oi-gnon/o-gnon à l'écrit. /ɔ.ɲõ/ à l'oral.

> Le g dans ce mot est-il une consonne ambisyllabique ?

Ce g est purement orthographique et n'a aucun impact sur la phonologie. Attention à ne pas prendre l'orthographe d'un mot pour sa représentation phonologie dans la lexique !

Comme tu le mentionnes, ognon vient du latin UNIONEM, probablement */u'niɔnẽː/ puis prononcé */o'ɲɔne/ en latin vernaculaire. En ancien français, ça donne /ɔ'ɲɔn/, puis /ɔ'ɲɔ̃n/ et enfin /ɔɲɔ̃/ en moyen français.

Parce que le son /ɲ/ provient principalement des séquence GN en latin (mais aussi de NI+Voyelle comme ici), il était orthographié avec ce digraphe en Ancien et Moyen Français. Cela pose cependant un problème, parce qu'un nombre important d'emprunts (déjà, à l'époque, au latin ou au grec) ont la même séquence de lettres prononcée /gn/. C'est le cas de gnose et gnou, mais aussi, par exemple, de magnétisme, d'abord prononcé /magnetism/ avant d'acquérir sa prononciation moderne /maɲetizm/ une fois répandu hors des cercles savants.

Au XVIème siècle, lors de la standardisation orthographique, on utilisait d'un moyen aujourd'hui disparu pour faire la différence entre /gn/ et /ɲ/: la seconde prononciation était écrite avec le trigraphe ign. Les anciens écrivaient donc campaigne, montaigne et besoigne pour les modernes campagne, montagne et besogne.

"Oignon" est l'une des rares survivances de cette convention orthographique (les autres, le philosophe Montaigne et le mot poigne, ont succombé à la prononciation orthographique). Ni son i ni son g n'ont une base étymologique, et ces deux sons n'ont jamais fait partie de l'évolution phonologique du mot.

> Peut-on savoir que le premier o [ɔ] de ognon est prononcé différemment du mot eau [o] en se fiant à l'orthographe du mot ? Peut-on prononcer [o] et si oui, cela affecte-t-il le découpage syllabique ?

La prononciation des voyelles moyennes inaccentuées varie énormément d'un locuteur à l'autre, sans impact sur la compréhension ou la signification en général (hormis quelques rares cas comme autant/OTAN ou botté/beauté).

Généralement, la prononciation originelle des sons orthographiés o est bien [ɔ], mais elle peut passer à [o] par harmonie vocalique avec une voyelle haute ou mi-haute dans la syllabe accentuée (par exemple, je prononce oser [oz̪eˑ]) ou par l'influence de la loi de position (voyelle mi-fermée en syllabe ouvert ; voyelle mi-ouverte en syllabe fermée).

Ognon peut donc beaucoup varier selon le dialecte. À la grosse louche, je m'attendrais à /ɔ.ɲõ/ en Belgique, à /o.njõ/ dans le nord de la France, à /o.ɲɔ̃/ dans le Midi et à /ɔ.ɲɒ̃ʊ̯̃/ au Quèbec. Mais ce n'est qu'une esquisse de la variabilité possible. La syllabification n'est par contre pas affectée.

Answer (score 2):

pour moi ça se prononce en 2 syllabes o-nion et le o se prononce exactement comme dans "eau". (cela dit les prononciations, surtout des voyelles, changent pas mal selon les coins de France :-) )

Comment: je ne pense pas qu'un français entende de différence entre "nion" et "gnon". Cela dit quand on descend dans le sud, et particulierement le sud-ouest, certaines consonnes usuellement muettes deviennent audibles (voire se rajoutent a l'oral là où elles n'existent pas à l'écrit: "Oh putainG conG". Mais je ne suis pas capable d'imaginer comment un pote Toulousain arriverait a prononcer un G audible dans "gnon".
Attention: dans ces zones là, le "i" de "oignon" s'entend souvent: ils disent "oi-(g)non" la ou les autres disent "o-nion".

Comment: Vous voulez dire un peu comme [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/12734/3177)? Si vous apportez des changements à votre réponse, je vous invite à l'étoffer avec ces expériences concrètes de la langue. Merci !