# Mots qui ne se prononcent pas du tout comme ils s'écrivent

Tags: prononciation

*[Cette liste de mots](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/vingt-mots-a-prononcer-enfin-correctement)*  ne donne que des nuances de prononciation.

Au contraire de ***flemme*** (*flème*), y a-t-il d'autres mots, tel que ***femme*** (*fame*), qui ne se prononcent pas du tout comme ils s'écrivent lorsque la même syllabe est prononcée d'une façon différente dans un autre contexte ?

P.S. : Les noms propres ne rentrent pas dans cette recherche.

***EDIT***

C'est une recherche de prononciation différente de l'écrit, et surtout de l'unicité de ce mot.

Parmi les réponses (liste provisoire de mots n'ayant pas de règle connue) :

- *Acu**punc**ture* et ***punc***h (un prononcé *on*).
- *P**oêl**e*  avec `ê` et *m**oel**le* avec `e` mais sans ligature `œ` se prononce *oil*.
- [***Oign***on](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17702/848) semble unique en France, mais pas au Québec *p**oign**ard* (oi prononcé o) ainsi que *p**oi**reau* en Belgique.
- ***Mon-sieur*** semble unique (et double !!).
- *F**emm**e* est unique (e --> *a*)
- *Exa**men*** est tout seul dans son cas (men prononcé *main*).

Comment: *Poële* s'écrit en fait *poêle*. C'est le seul mot (avec poêlon/poêler) a utiliser la combinaison *oê*. Je n'ai trouvé qu'un seul autre mot contentant *oel*, *moelle/moellon* et dérivés où *oe* est aussi prononcé *oi*, ou du moins devrait l'être car on entend de plus en plus *mouélleux* comme on entend aussi *poéller*...

Comment: *Examen* est le seul mot en *-men* prononcé *-main* (contrairement à  abdomen, acumen, amen, cyclamen, cérumen, dolmen, foramen, germen, gramen, hymen, lumen, spécimen).

Comment: Une expression, pas un mot: «Entre quatre yeux», prononcé, dans sa version la plus concise, /ɑ̃tkatzjø/. Entre les lettres disparues et le Z ajouté, on respecte au moins la séquence des sons écrits que l'on se donne la peine de prononcer.

Comment: Je fais des listes chaque jour de ces mots. Aujourd'hui : tapote "tah **puht**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En voici quelques uns:

- acup**un**cture
- cacah**u**ète
- déc**e**mment (et tous les adverbes dérivés d'un adjectif en *-ent*)
- e**c**zéma
- **e**nivrer
- **eu**
- exam**en**
- m**on**si**eur**
- p**un**ch
- se**c**ond
- soi**x**ante
- sol**e**nnel
- tran**s**it

Comment: en fait, (tiens, je me rends compte qu'on prononce le "t"), pour compléter 'décemment', tous les adverbes dont l'adjectif se termine par "ent" s'écrivent emment et se prononcent ament. Par exemple, prudent, violent, impatient, diligent, éloquent, intelligent...

Comment: *Acu**punc**ture* et ***punc**h* sont deux mots qui ne se prononcent pas comme ils s'écrivent. Est-ce que *femme* à une 'petite sœur phonétique' ?

Comment: @radouxju C'est vrai, alors que ceux dérivées d'adjectifs en *-ant* se terminent en *-amment* (bruyant →bruyamment).

Comment: Non, *femme* est unique (avec ses dérivés bien sûr, comme *ex-femme*, *sage-femme*, voire *sagefemme*).

Comment: Merci, on reconnaît bien là la spécificité du français et la place qu'elle tient dans la littérature (et la vie des Français)  :) -- J'ai complété ma question pour préciser le sens de cette recherche. Rien ne vous empêche de compléter la liste :)

Comment: Votre liste est très intéressante, toutefois je me permets de contester la présence d' "eczéma": le fait de dire "egzéma" n'est pas une règle, mais une déformation mécanique inévitable du "k" en "g", tout comme "carnet de chèques" pourrait se confondre avec "livret bohémien" (si je puis me permettre cette petite touche humoristique)...

Comment: @BBBreiz en effet, certains dictionnaires admettent [ks]. Le seul autre mot contenant *cz* est *czar* dont la prononciation est elle aussi flottante [tsar]/[dsar] voire [ksar].

Answer (score 2):

L'orthographe n'est pas purement phonétique: Ainsi, le groupe "er" se prononce différemment selon les mots: Dans les verbes du 1er groupe, il se prononcer "é": "*manger*","*bouger*","*aimer*", mais dans certains noms ou adjectifs, il se prononce "ère" : "*mer*","*amer*"...

L'évolution phonétique de la langue laisse aussi des traces dans l'orthographe, qui n'est pas forcément censée suivre les modifications de prononciation: Ainsi, le mot "*fils*" se prononce "*fiss*" s'il s'agit de filiation, mais "*fil*" s'il s'agit d'une corde.

On sait que le groupe "ca" a évolué au fil des siècles, se prononçant tantôt "ka", tantôt "cha" et tantôt "tcha", ce qui explique l'existence de voisins sémantiques tels que "cariole" et "chariot" où, cette fois, l'orthographe a dû suivre l'évolution de la prononciation...

Il y a bien d'autres exemples, et c'est le mérite de l'orthographe de nous permettre de retracer certaines évolutions de la langue, mais aussi la parenté entre des mots dont les sens respectifs ont lentement dérivé dans le temps.

Comment: *Les poules du couvent couvent* (simple : un couvent ne couve pas) ou *Mes fils ont coupé mes fils* (plus compliqué, car on peut mettre le pluriel de *fil* ou *fils* au début ou à la fin (en admettant que le fil à couper le beurre puisse découper un fils), sont des exemples connus et répertoriés. Ce n'est pas le sens de ma recherche : les exceptions 'inexplicables' plutôt que les règles de prononciations connues.

Comment: Alors je suggère "poële", dont je ne sais pas pourquoi on le prononce "poil"...

Comment: *Poële* n'existe pas et ne se prononce donc pas comme *noël*. Il s'orthographie *poêle* et se prononce *poil*, comme *moelle* se prononce *moil* ...

Answer (score 2):

La graphie "e" se prononce "a" dans les mots suivants: couenne (et ses dérivés couenneux, couenneuse), femme, moelle (et ses dérivés moelleux, moelleuse, moelleusement, moellon, moellonnage), solennel (et ses dérivés solennelle,  solennité, solennellement. En avez-vous d'autres?

Comment: Pour ma part je prononce *couenne* comme il s'écrit et l'ai toujours entendu ainsi.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a few, but off the top of my head: 
- 'oignon', pronounced oh-gnon as opposed the intuitive oie-gnon.
- 'nous faisons', pronounced feuh-zon as opposed to the intuitive fait-zon.

And many many names of places or people, such as the Laguiole knifes, pronounced 'layol' instead of 'lag - i - ol'

Comment: *Oignon* est cité dans la liste, y a-t-il d'autres cas ou `oi` se prononce `o` ? -- J'ai complété ma question pour les noms propres (quoique je ne connaisse pas d'autre `gui` qui se transforme en `yo`. Faisons est intéressant, ou passe de `é` a `e` (il y a seulement un accent prononcé ou pas), mais cela n'est pas le changement de voyelle `e ~ è` à `a` comme dans *femme*

Comment: En France, je ne crois pas. Par contre, au Québec, 'oign' est souvent prononcé comme 'ogn', par exemple avec 'poignard', 'poigne', etc

Comment: En France on a deux écritures : *poigne* et son dérivé argotique *pogne*. Maintenant, avec la nouvelle orthographe qui a fait couler beaucoup d'encre, *ognon* est accepté (par l'Académie, mais pas par tous les correcteurs d'orthographe :)

Comment: @cl-r en Belgique on prononce "poireau" avec un o (po - rau)

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax votre lien est intégré dans la question :) peut-être que *moignon* a les mêmes variations dans toute la francophonie.

Comment: @radouxju -- J'ai complété la liste des déformations du 'oi' en 'o'.