# L'orthographe « ognon » a-t-elle une date de péremption ?

Tags: orthographe, histoire, linguistique, standard, éducation

On sait que l'[*ognon*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ognon) est une variante orthographique [rectifiée](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=oignon&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=3175) (1990) de l'[*oignon*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oignon) dont l'orthographe est [tributaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17702) d'une ancienne convention orthographique. Très généralement « [[l]es rectifications de l’orthographe ont été proposées par la France en 1990. L’Académie française les a par la suite approuvées](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3195) » et « à l’instar de l’Académie française qui, en 1991, déclarait que les anciennes graphies demeuraient admises et qu’on ne pouvait pénaliser les nouvelles graphies, l’Office québécois de la langue française estime que ni les graphies traditionnelles, ni les nouvelles graphies proposées ne doivent être considérées comme fautives. » (BDL). Par ailleurs on pouvait trouver la graphie sans le *i* dans [*Ac.5*](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/philologic4/publicdicos/query?report=bibliography&head=ognon) (1798) et elle n'est donc pas « nouvelle », sauf qu'un dictionnaire comme [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/oignon/55788/difficulte) *en ligne*, par exemple, n'en fait pas mention...

---

Dans son [*Éloge de l'oignon*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/eloge-de-loignon) du 6 avril 2017, l'académicien M. [Frédéric Vitoux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_Vitoux) (F15) dit :

> Convenons-en : le « i » d’oignon aurait pu tomber naturellement au fil
>   des siècles, comme « montaigne » est devenu « montagne », « besoigne »
>   « besogne » ou « roignon » « rognon », et nul n’y aurait trouvé à
>   redire. Dans les propositions de rectification de l’orthographe de
>   1990, la graphie « ognon » avait été reconnue comme non fautive, sous
>   réserve que l’usage, comme pour d’autres mots, l’entérine.
>
> Mais voilà, il n’en a rien été. [...]

Et l'auteur d'évoquer entre autres la résistance et la fidélité des producteurs maraîchers, et la qualité populaire de l'orthographe *oignon*. Le constat que l'usage n'a pas entériné l'orthographe rectifiée impliquerait à mon avis qu'il existait un délai pendant lequel l'usage devait se l'approprier...

---

- L'orthographe rectifiée *ognon* a-t-elle une date de péremption après
  laquelle on pourrait objectivement croire qu'elle ne ferait l'objet
  d'aucun emploi ; est-ce maintenant ; a-t-on des détails sur l'usage
  de l'orthographe *ognon* et y a-t-il des manifestations de son refus
  plus généralement, ou dans d'autres contextes d'application comme
  dans le monde de l'éducation par exemple ?
- Peut-on comparer avec un autre cas de changement orthographique dans
  l'histoire de la langue française et donner une idée du temps qu'il
  peut prendre pour qu'un changement soit entériné par l'usage, abstraction
  faite des moyens de communication ; 1990 est-elle vraiment une année
  pertinente et s'agit-il d'un délai supérieur à 25 ans qui coure
  depuis la rectification, et est-ce significatif etc. ?

Comment: Larousse **en ligne** librement accessible n'est pas une référence valable - à mes yeux du moins ! Que dit la dernière édition du [Petit Robert](http://www.lerobert.com/dictionnaires-generalistes/dictionnaire-le-petit-robert-2017-grand-format.html) ?

Comment: "Dans le Petit Larousse 2012, qui a bénéficié d'une refonte totale, "nous avons pour la première fois fait figurer la nouvelle orthographe en début d'article avec un statut clair et identifié par un symbole, juste après l'orthographe traditionnelle", note Jacques Florent, responsable des dictionnaires de langue française chez Larousse. "On informe le lecteur, il décide"."  Lu dans [20 minutes du 29/09/11](http://www.20minutes.fr/societe/796668-20110929-ognon-nenufar-vingt-ans-apres-nouvelle-orthographe-pietine).

Comment: @Laure Merci, bien c'est une source comme une autre, mais pas la même que le _Larousse_ papier c'est vrai. L'énoncé servait surtout à expliquer ma recherche, incomplète, et ma réflexion, et je n'ai ni le _Robert_ ni le _Larousse_ sous la main. On s'attendrait à ce qu'on donne l'information en effet et c'est aussi pourquoi j'ai mentionné la version en ligne. Par ailleurs qu'en est-il de l'usage, progresse-t-il ou non, les parents ont-ils transmis à leurs enfants une réticence à employer _ognon_ ; la résistance des maraîchers est-elle généralisée, combien de temps faut-il pour le savoir ?

Comment: Je doute qu'il existe un délai défini au delà duquel l'orthographe rectifiée ***o**gnon* deviendrait caduque.

Tout ne peut être que spéculation mais il est possible (et souhaitable à mon avis) que cette orthographe finisse par s'imposer, si les éditeurs et les enseignants y mettent du leur, les maraîchers suivront, ou alors la prononciation d'***oi**gnon* se calquera peut-être sur son écriture et deviendra **/waɲɔ̃/**, c'est à dire : «l'oi - gnon », que l'on entend parfois…

Comment: N'hésitez pas à répondre, qu'on couvre le lexique, d'autres sources, un cas historique comparable, un corpus etc. et une réponse peut aussi contenir une part opinion, objectivement motivée, tous concourant aussi à l'usage. Merci !

Comment: Un cas similaire, qui continue de faire débat aujourd'hui, mais faiblement et dans une indifférence presque complète: quand doit-on utiliser *deuxième*, quand *second*? Certains prennent position, certain même fortement, mais la plupart des gens sont complètement indifférents face à cette interrogation. Voir [l’opinion](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4817) de la *Banque de dépannage linguistique*, mesurée et montrant bien à quel point cette question n’est plus très contoversée aujourd’hui.

Answer (score 2):

Le français étant une langue pour laquelle il existe une académie organisée, contrairement à d'autres langues comme l'anglais, les principales évolutions "valables" sont celles qu'elle inscrit à son dictionnaire. Evidemment, cela n'est que théorique, dans la mesure où le français familier évolue parallèlement aux décisions de cette académie, mais dans le sens de ta question, à savoir la disparition d'une graphie, sa décision est plutôt fiable.
Il est donc, à mon avis, à considérer que la graphie *ognon* est désuète, mais valide d'un point de vue académique, et ce sans limite de durée jusqu'à décision explicite de l'Académie.

Je rajouterais que cela est d'autant plus vrai que la persistance de la graphie désuète a été entre autres décidée par l'Académie française.

Comment: Le français n'est pas « régi » par l'Académie française qui, bien qu'étant un organisme officiel, n'a d'autorité que consultative et morale. Le pouvoir législatif et règlementaire est détenu par les autorités compétentes de chaque pays francophone (ministères, parlements, etc.) qui seules peuvent légiférer sur l'orthographe ou la grammaire dans leur domaine de compétence.

Comment: @jlliagre En effet. Je rectifie.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'existe pas de délai prédéfini au delà duquel l'orthographe rectifiée *ognon* deviendrait caduque.

*Oignon* est une graphie désuète, ou du moins aurait dû le devenir au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, lorsque la réforme de l'orthographe de l'époque décida de supprimer le **i** précédant **gn** qui servait jusque-là à distinguer la prononciation mouillée « nyeu » \ɲ\ de celle ou les lettres g et n sont séparées \gn\, comme dans « gnome » ou « agnostique ».

Pour certains mots, ce changement s'est opéré sans encombre :

- Monta**ign**e → monta**gn**e
- Ga**ign**er → ga**gn**er
- Campa**ign**e → campa**gn**e

Pour d'autres mots, le changement d'orthographe n'a pas pris et la persistance de la graphie ancienne a entraîné un changement de prononciation, par exemple :

- Po**ign**ée se prononçait auparavant *[pognée](https://www.littre.org/definition/poign%C3%A9e)*
- Ara**ign**ée se prononçait auparavant *[aragnée](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aragn%C3%A9e)*
- Mo**ign**on se prononçait auparavant *[mognon](https://www.littre.org/definition/moignon)*

Apparemment, seul *oignon* a réussi à préserver sa prononciation traditionnelle tout en conservant une graphie obsolète.

Si l'orthographe rectifiée ne réussit toujours pas à s'imposer, il est possible que dans le futur, à l'instar de moignon, ***oignon*** finisse par se prononcer comme il s'écrit /**waɲɔ̃**/, ce que l'on entend déjà parfois. Si cette nouvelle prononciation devient la norme, la graphie ***ognon*** n'aura plus de justification et la recommandation deviendra caduque.

Comment: Pour information, mon grand-oncle a pour nom de famille Deloignon, et je l'ai toujours entendu prononcer /dəlwaɲɔ̃/, ce qui va dans votre sens.

Answer (score 2):

Une langue, la francophonie, appartient à ses utilisateurs et non pas à un pays.

> La reine d'Angleterre n'a pas validé le terme anglophone `to skype`, qui est pourtant utilisé à de nombreuses reprises, par exemple :
>
> > `skype me at 2 pm`

Selon moi, l'usage courant fera foi au fil du temps.

L'usage de cette nouvelle orthographe peut être encouragé par des utilisations dans l'administration ou lors de correction d'examens réputés (baccalauréat, etc) ou bien encore par des publications dans des ouvrages de références comme les dictionnaires, par exemple.

Chocolatine figure dans le Larousse et le Petit Robert (depuis 2011), mais est utilisée depuis de nombreuse années.

Lol figure aussi dans le dictionnaire, mais je me vois mal l'utiliser lors d'un écrit institutionnel.

Le délais de 25ans ne semble pas pertinent, des mots comme `moult` ou `désuet` peuvent très bien devenir incontournable du langage populaire dans le prochain siècle ou bien disparaître...